# CreateScaledBitmap causing Grow heap

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, camera, bitmapimage

I use a custom camera which I open on a Handler thread to take photo on my jpeg callback.

I want to store my picture in cache after scaling down the picture so the pictures fits in a 1000 x 1000 size keeping its ratio.

To do so I take the picture from the jpeg callback using :

```
private Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

        Bitmap realImage;
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        options.inPurgeable=true;                  
        options.inInputShareable=true;          
        realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length,options);
    }
```

So far so good, I can take as many pictures as I want, no memory problem...

But when I want to write the picture to cache I need to scaled it down using :

```
private class addThumbnailASYNC extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmap) {

        Bitmap image = bitmap[0]; 
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
            width = MAX_SIZE_IMAGE;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = MAX_SIZE_IMAGE;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }

        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);  

    }
```

The problem is when I use 
`image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`
I get a Grow heap which I think will lead to an out of memory if I take many pictures.

There are 3 things that I don't understand :

- When I use `options.inSampleSize` the picture should be scaled by 4 so why createScaledBitmap causes a grow heap ?
- If I don't use `createScaledBitmap` and that I write the image to cache I never get the grow heap why ? The `inSampleSize` should gave me more heavy file than the one I create using scaledBitmap ?
- I need to avoid memory heap, but how to avoid grow heap because I have no choice using createdScaledBitmap and my picture will be always taken by the camera, I feel stuck.

Comment: did you note that `bitmapRatio > 0` is always true ?

Comment: did you note that `doInBackground` (as you have written) is equivalent to : `image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, MAX_SIZE_IMAGE, height, true);`  (I'm sure this is not what you want, but this what you do)

Comment: Yes it is. always > 0 do think that createScaledBitmap give a bigger  file ?

Comment: createScaledBitmap create a **new** bitmap in memory so yes, it consumme more heap because you now have 2 bitmaps in memory (not because of the new image size)

Comment: @ben74 yes i do more stuff that that in doInBackground

Comment: @ben75 so i always get a heap no matter what i do ? because i will always have 2 bitmap if i do scaled down one bitmap

Comment: `bitmap[0] = null` will nullify ref to the original image so GC will collect it and free memory